# how can I increase font size of each cell on entire excel sheet effeciently?

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

how can I increase font size of each cell on entire excel sheet effeciently ?
When I use foreach loop excel goes non responsive.

Comment: Have you tried using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`?

Comment: `Each cell on entire sheet`, does it mean that for each cell you need a different font size? (pretty irrational) or does it mean the answer given by John? Either way it's recommnded to use `ScreenUpdating = False` as Justin pointed out. Please comment.

Comment: I have already tried with what Justin has suggested and yes for each cell I need different font size , I actually want to increase the font size of each cell in the sheet by some seed ( by some const value ) , but when i try to iterate throug all cells in active sheet and add into the existing font size , it takes hell lot of time

Answer (score 4):

Try this Sub:

```
  Sub IncreaseFontSize()    
     ActiveSheet.Cells.Font.Size = 14
  End Sub
```

... Just change the size to whatever you want.

Comment: +1 as simple as that (why don't I ever stumble on these sort of questions!)

Comment: LOL - Couldn't agree more - Some times you just get a gimme :)

Answer (score 3):

No need for VBA (unless of course part of another macro):

Simply select all worksheets (activate the first worksheet and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the last worksheet), then select all cells (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>) and enter the desired font size in the `Home` tab's font size drop down or use the `Increase Font Size´ button.

Comment: ... Just as nice and eloquent a solution! +1